# Windows Server 2019 - Ping of IP and Computer Name Don't Match, but Should

Tags: dns, windows-server-2019

I recently gave a computer on the domain a new IP through a reservation in DHCP. When I ping the computer by name it reports for the old IP address (there is now a VOIP based phone at the old IP). I've checked in DNS on the server. The forward zone had the old IP address. I corrected the entry and refreshed. Pinging the name still pings the old IP. What am I dong wrong?

PS: As you can probably tell, I am a novice with Windows Server administration, but I want to learn. If there is different forum that would be more appropriate for my type of questions, feel free to advise me.

Comment: Try the following: 1) Flush the client Windows DNS cache `ipconfig /flushdns`. 2) Check the contents of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` for hardcoded hostnames. 3) Reboot the client computer.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. That is great information about the hosts file too. I've looked around in the interface and don't see a way to accept this answer or give credit. If I can, and you like, feel free to explain that to me.

Comment: Which suggestion worked?

Comment: The flush DNS. I checked the hosts file. It is empty, so no problem there. Thanks again.